# How can I pass self to the unbound method of a separate class

Tags: python, django

I'm working to update the django-recurrence package to work with my version of Python/Django. What I'm coming up against is the line at https://github.com/emperorcezar/django-recurrence/blob/master/recurrence/fields.py#L103

```
return super(RecurrenceField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

The class calling that line is RecurrenceModelField which is a wrapper of sorts (but not a subclass) around RecurrenceField.

At some point this super() black magic must have worked, but it works no longer. Now I'm wondering how to replicate this functionality?

Is there a simple fix to get it working again, or will I have to refactor?

Comment: If `self` is not an instance of `RecurrenceField`, this has never worked.

Comment: First time I've ever tried to use it, so you could very well be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function was added in commit [54909d74fe](https://github.com/emperorcezar/django-recurrence/commit/54909d74fec5b9694eb054b70452dc03163b1e0e). It wouldn't have ever worked.

The `RecurrenceModelField` object is a subclass of Django's `OneToOneField`. Looking at the [base class formfield method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1045), the argument to the bound method is always going to be an instance of `RecurrenceModelField`.

I think the most likely explanation is that it was a copy/paste error - since the [same line](https://github.com/emperorcezar/django-recurrence/commit/54909d74fec5b9694eb054b70452dc03163b1e0e#L0R40) appears in the `RecurrenceField` class method. The author probably copied it and forgot to change the class name.

You should change that line to:

```
return super(RecurrenceModelField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```